# Percentage of elements - Css

Tags: css

How do I determine what the percentage of an element should be in CSS?
Same with pixels.

For example:

```
.box {
    background:red;
    float:left;
    margin:1.8949%;
    width:29.2939478%
}
```

How does one come up with 29.234%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I just look at elements and decide how much space I want them to fill up. If I want say a quarter, I would use 25%. Sometimes, I just take the number of elements I have in a div, and if I want them equal size, divide the number of elements into 100. It's all up to you and what you want for sizing. For specific numbers and percents, they most likely come from fractions calculated into percents, like if you want 5/17 of the page of an element for example, that's not a perfect percent. Just experiment and find what you like and looks best

Comment: Just to complement: The programmer who coded this should have written a comment explaining why `29.234` was the number chosen. In javascript and other programming languages we try to avoid such meaningless numbers by naming variables and functions according to their purpose and usage, but there's no such a thing in CSS so commenting is the way to go, or doing more abstract classing maybe.